# No me carga el sitio web al agregar el controller de registrar clientes en PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy teniendo un problema cuando agrego la funcion en la vista desde el controller para registrar un cliente y no sé que podría ser, les voy a compartir mi codigo del controller, el model y la vista.

Si no se incluye el controller, la vista se ve normal como quiero que se vea, pero cuando lo agrego la página no me carga, aún estoy trabajando de formal local, no está en el servidor. Acá solo incluyo las plantillas.

```
<?php
include "../Layout/Layouts.php";
?>
```

Y la vista se ve así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando lo incluyo me sale el siguiente error.

```
<?php
include "../Layout/Layouts.php";
include "../Controller/IniciarSesionController.php";
?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo cual me parece muy extraño porque en otros proyectos he usado la misma función y no me sucede esto.

Código del model:

```
<?php

include "conexion.php";

function RegistrarUsuarioModel(){
    $instancia = AbrirBaseDatos();

    if(!empty($_POST["btnRegistrarse"])){
        if(!empty($_POST["txtNombre"]) AND !empty($_POST["txtNacionalidad"]) AND !empty($_POST["txtUsuario"]) AND !empty($_POST["txtEmail"]) AND !empty($_POST["txtNumTelefono"])
            AND !empty($_POST["txtPassword"]) AND !empty($_POST["txtConPass"])){
                if($_POST["txtPassword"] == $_POST["txtConPass"]){
                    $nombre = $_POST["txtnombre"];
                    $nacionalidad = $_POST["txtNacionalidad"];
                    $usuario = $_POST["txtUsuario"];
                    $password = $_POST["txtPassword"];
                    $telefono = $_POST["txtNumTelefono"];
                    $email = $_POST["txtEmail"];
                    $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    
                    $registrarUsuario = $instancia -> query("CALL SP_USUARIO_REGISTRAR('$nombre', '$nacionalidad', '$usuario', '$hash', '$telefono', '$email');");
                } else {
                    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Verifica que las contraseñas coincidan</div>';
                }



                if($registrarUsuario > 0){
                    echo '<script>
                    Swal.fire({
                        icon: "success",
                        title: "Te has registrado correctamente",
                        text: "Muchas gracias por su registro",
                        showConfirmButton: false,
                        timer: 2500
                    });
                        </script>';
                } else {
                    echo '<script>
                    Swal.fire({
                        icon: "error",
                        title: "Debes llenar todos los campos",
                        text: "Verifica los campos que tienen un *",
                        showConfirmButton: false,
                        timer: 2500
                    });
                        </script>';
                }

        } else {
            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Revisa que los campos con un * no estén vacios</div>';
        }
    }

    CerrarBaseDatos($instancia);
}

?>
```

Código del controller

```
<?php

include "../../model/IniciarSesionModel.php";

/*Funcion para registrar un administrador*/
function RegistrarUsuarioModel(){
    $registrarUsuario = RegistrarUsuarioModel();
  }

?>
```

Vista del formulario

```
<form class="form-signup" method="POST" name="form"> 
                <?php RegistrarUsuarioModel();?>
                <label for="fullname">Nombre completo</label>
                <input class="form-styling" type="text" name="txtNombre" placeholder=""/>
                <label for="fullname">Nacionalidad</label>
                <select name="txtNacionalidad" class="form-styling">
                    
                </select>
                <label for="txtUsuario">Usuario</label>
                <input class="form-styling" type="text" name="txtUsuario" placeholder=""/>
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input class="form-styling" type="email" name="txtEmail" placeholder=""/>
                <label for="txtNumTelefono">Número de teléfono</label>
                <input class="form-styling" type="text" name="txtNumTelefono" placeholder=""/>
                <label for="password">Contraseña</label>
                <input class="form-styling" type="text" name="txtPassword" placeholder=""/>
                <label for="confirmpassword">Confirma tu contraseña</label>
                <input class="form-styling" type="text" name="txtConPass" placeholder=""/>
                <div class="btn-animate">
                    <input type="submit" value="Registrarse" class="btn-signin" name="btnRegistrarse">
                </div>
            </form>
```

Tal vez sería importante mencionar que en la misma vista estoy incluyendo 2 formularios uno de inicio de sesión y otro de registro, pero no creo que eso esté generando este error. Y además todo el proyecto está funcionando bien, solo es esta vista la que genera problemas.

Answer (score 0):

Tenía mal nombradas las funciones en el controller por eso no me estaba cargando la página.

```
function RegistrarUsuarioController(){
    $registrarUsuario = RegistrarUsuarioModel();
  }
```